# How to accomplish nested resources with Rails, react, and Redux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, redux, react-router

My project has 3 models: users, concerts and reviews. I do not quite understand how to change between rendering nested and un-nested resources with React and redux. For example, having my reviews container render all reviews, a user's reviews, or a concert's reviews. In rails land this was easy because I could just define `@reviews` based on if I received a concert id or user id in the params. But for react/ redux I do not know how to achieve this.

Currently I have reducers for reviews and for userReviews. My reviews container switches between them based on the url pathname. Do I need another reducer for concertReviews? That seems dirty. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I just pushed those actions all into the reviews reducer and actions.